Has Putin ever visited Tanya Savicheva's memorial?
(Not sure if this should be on the History SE)
Tanya Savicheva's memorial is apparently well-known in St. Petersburg, which is also where Putin grew up, so he is presumably aware of its existence. Has he ever visited it?
I'm interested in visits both before & after Putin became President. If he has never visited it, I'm also interested in whether he has ever said something about it.

Is this question related to a particular news item? It could be useful to quote it.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad I'm not keen. It'll just make people speculate on how to interpret this as a push question (I bet some people are already trying to think of ways to do that).

It seems to me a bit out of blue - why should he visit this specific memorial? Why do you think Savicheva is important for him? I mean - I don't quite understand the underlying motivation. (Note - I wouldn't vote for closure, since I posted an answer. Also, I didn't downvote - IMHO, if some people find my answer to this Q. useful, it means that the Q. itself is useful.)

I lived for a long time in St. Petersburg (called Leningrad in the USSR in honor of Lenin, the head of the terrorist Bolshevik regime during its early years). I visited many traditional historic places in this city, and spoke on these topics with many natives of Leningrad. This is the first time I heard about Tanya Savicheva's memorial. I highly doubt your claim: "Tanya Savicheva's memorial is apparently well-known in St. Petersburg", and recommend that your revise your question appropriately.

@TimurShtatland there's always going to be a sampling bias here, but see e.g. https://www.indexoncensorship.org/2022/11/what-russias-children-think-about-the-war-in-ukraine/. To quote, "[Tanya's] last entry is known to almost everyone in St Petersburg".

@Allure The quote says this about the diary entry: 'One of the most poignant Russian documents of the 1941–45 war was the diary of Tanya Savicheva, a young girl trapped in the Siege of Leningrad. Her last entry is known to almost everyone in St Petersburg: “Everyone is dead, only Tanya is left”.' Your claim is about the memorial: "Tanya Savicheva's memorial is apparently well-known in St. Petersburg"

@TimurShtatland sure, but if you are aware of the diary entry, I would also expect you to be aware of the memorial. Were you aware of the entry but not the memorial?

I vaguely recall the diary entry among other Leningrad siege related history bits. I had no idea there was a memorial until now. But my personal story, of course, is just only one bit of info. I have no statistics. :)

@TimurShtatland +1 for honest answer. I have no statistics, either. =)

If the site's as important and visited as claimed, it is quite possible, technically, that he could have gone on a school trip there growing up in St. Petersburg.  Which would probably not be remembered by anyone, except him.  Now, why any of this would have any political relevance for this site escapes me.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the siege of Leningrad is an example of using starvation as a weapon of war, which resulted in a million deaths - you probably understand how this can be used for propaganda purposes :-) Though it is also claimed that it didn't happen without Stalin's help, like Holodomor.

I'm voting to reopen because this question is about a current political leader. Saying the question has no political relevance is effectively asking for a motivation, and one is provided, then the question becomes a push question.

Tanya Savicheva is a Russian equivalent of Anne Frank - her diary documents the slow death from starvation of her family during the Siege of Leningrad during World War 2. Due to the high profile of this document,  Vladimir Putin, as well as most Russians of his generation, are aware of it. Indeed, Savicheva is referenced, e.g., in German President Joachim Gauck's letter to Putin, written in 2014:

With the people of St Petersburg I remember the martyrdom endured by so many innocents, so many women, men and children, who were deliberately starved to death. From devastating records like Tanya Savicheva’s diary we know the screams and tears, the despair and never-ending hunger, the struggle of the besieged to survive. The immense scale of this human suffering is something we still find beyond comprehension.

(emphasis is mine)
It is also worth mentioning that Putin's family lived through the blockade of Leningrad, and his older brother died from starvation as well (see also here):

Putin's birth was preceded by the deaths of two brothers: Albert, born in the 1930s, died in infancy, and Viktor, born in 1940, died of diphtheria and starvation in 1942 during the Siege of Leningrad by Nazi Germany's forces in World War II.

However, her memorial is but one among the many memorials commemorating this tragedy - indeed, it is not even mentioned in the relevant part of the Wikipedia article about the siege. Unless, the Q. refers to some specific news item, it is not clear why Putin would single out this memorial for a visit.
Remark
Amusing trivia: apparently at some point in his life Vladimir Putin lived not far from the house of Tanya Savicheva (2nd line of Vasilievsky Island, 17 and and 2nd line of Vasilievsky Island, 13/6 (Vasilievsky Island, Bolshoy Prospect, 6) respectively), although, as far as I can judge, it is not where he lived as a child.

As a person born in USSR I can assure you most people outside of former Leningrad have no idea who she is. This topic (Leningrad's siege) was well known but It was a dark and gladly avoided subject all along. Very formal and boring.

I heard that the siege of Leningrad, its heroic supply across the Ladoga Lake, and the records of suffering (including the Savicheva's diary Only Tanya is left) were among the staples of the Victory day celebrations.... which were quite an important part of the Soviet ethos.

She was never mentioned in my school or at any parade or celebration. And I lived in a million people city of USSR. So you are very far from reality that I witnessed in person regardless of what you "heard". Maybe 5-7% who liked going deeper into history knew her name, most people in USSR tried to have fun and not read or study about dying girls. Cause it was first unpleasant, second - very formalized by the state and avoided. But it's of course funny to read how confidently you write about "most Russians" having no idea about real life in USSR. :)

@Groovy yeah, nowadays any kid born in 1990 claims that they know what the USSR was like...

FWTW, the 80th commemoration of the lifting of the siege has some Western press coverage.

The Russian city of St. Petersburg on Saturday marked the 80th anniversary of the end of a devastating World War II siege by Nazi forces with a series of memorial events attended by Russian President Vladimir Putin and close allies.
The Kremlin leader laid flowers at a monument to fallen Soviet defenders of the city, then called Leningrad, on the banks of the Neva River, and then at Piskarevskoye Cemetery, where hundreds of thousands of siege victims are buried.

It doesn't alas detail at which of the monuments Putin went. Perhaps coverage in Russian will have more details on that. Actually, TASS details that

On the 80th anniversary of the end of the Siege of Leningrad, Russian President Vladimir Putin laid flowers at a monument at Nevsky Pyatachok (Neva Bridgehead) in the Leningrad Region [...]
Nevsky Pyatachok (Neva Bridgehead) is one of the most terrible and heroic episodes in the Battle of Leningrad. On the night of September 20, 1941, the forward battalion of the 115th Infantry Division, using fishing boats and homemade rafts from the Nevskaya Dubrovka area, managed to secretly cross to the left bank of the Neva and knock out the Germans from their forward positions, gaining control of a piece of coastal land.

So, apparently Putin favored the more 'heroic' monuments relating to the siege, at least on that occasion.
OTOH he does like to go to the unveiling of new monuments of that kind, i.e. in memory of victims (AP again):

On Saturday afternoon, Putin was joined by Belarusian President Alexander Lukashenko in Gatchina, a town outside St. Petersburg that once housed camps for Soviet prisoners of war, for the unveiling of a statue commemorating civilians killed during the Nazi onslaught.

